# SQL Server, FK: Check in the (1) side NoCheck in the (Many) side

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, check-constraints

Suppose I have an ActiveCustomers table with some FKs (eg CountryID),
and I also have a NonActiveCustomers with the same FKs.
When I insert a new line to ActiveCustomers - the system must check the "1" side (from 1:N) to verify the CountryID (or whatever) exists.
When I move a line from ActiveCustomers to NonActiveCustomers - I don't need the system to verify it again because it has already been done when the line was originally inserted into ActiveCustomers.
In this case I can create  a Check FK constraint on ActiveCustomers,
and a NoCheck FK constraint on NonActiveCustomers;
but the problem is that when I delete lines from the "1" side table (Countries), I want the system to check in both "N" tables that the operation is allowed: I don't want to have orphaned lines there.
How can I do that? The Nocheck disables all validations in the inserts to NonActiveCustomers and in the deletions & updates (in Countries), even when I specify explicitly On Delete No Action On Update No Action.
Of course, I can create a Trigger on Countries in order to verify that the Delete or Update are correct, but is there a way to do that using the constraint mechanism?

Comment: What is the `NoCheck` aspect doing for you if you're not wanting orphans to exist?

Comment: Damien- I'm not sure I understood your question..
Anyway: when I insert a line from ActiveCustomers to NonActiveCustomers - I don't want the system to check the constraint, its redundsnt; 
but when I delete From Countries I want the system to verify it wouldn't convert lines in NonActiveCustomers into orphands.

Comment: But would it actually cause you any **problems** if the constraint was checked? It seems that you're trying to achieve some perceived efficiency by removing the check - but I'm not sure whether that's your only purpose and whether you've actually verified that it will provide any benefit to you. So I was wondering if there was some other reason you wanted to remove the check.

Comment: We had some waits problems with an historical data table with 6 FKs.
Those FKs are responsible for no more of 10% of the load, however I was curioused about it from a technical perspective,
and I guess the NoCheck disables all checks.
Thank you!